# jQuery Chosen Plugin - selection between options and a default

Tags: jquery, jquery-chosen

This is the jQuery Code:

```
$('.chosen-select').change(function(){
    var only_me = $(this).find('.only-me');
    var opts = $(this).find('option').not(only_me);
    if($(only_me).length){
        if($(opts).is(':selected')){
            $(only_me).attr('selected',false);
        }
        else if(!$(opts).is(':selected')){
            $(only_me).attr('selected',true);
        }
        else if($(only_me).is(':selected')){
            $(opts).attr('selected',false);
        }
    }
    $(this).trigger('chosen:updated');
});
```

This is the HTML

```
<select class="chosen-select" data-placeholder="Choose Marital Status..." multiple="multiple">
    <option class="only-me" selected>Doesn't Matter</option>
    <option>Un Married</option>
    <option>Divorced</option>
</select>
```

So, The Thing is,

1. If I select Doesn't matter, The options should be unselected
2. If I select Other Options, Doesn't Matter should be unselected
3. If nothing is selected, Select the Doesn't Matter

Please Help me fix this and thanks in advance

Comment: If you down vote, then please **point out the reason**

Comment: You're not describing what's wrong with the above code; is only one use case incorrect? Is it showing Javascript errors?

Comment: Also, out of curiosity, why not two checkboxes: Unmarried and Divorced, and if neither is checked, interpret that as doesn't matter?

Comment: No js errors, its just that i didn't know, How to check prev and current state of the select box

Comment: its a search form and so, its not the only select box am using with chosen

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution myself:

```
$('.only-me').parent('.chosen-select').each(function(){
    var prev = $(this).find('option:selected');
    $(this).change(function(){
        var current = $(this).children('option:selected');
        var only_me = $(this).children('.only-me');
        var opts = $(this).children('option').not(only_me);
        if(prev.hasClass('only-me') && current.not('.only-me')){
            only_me.attr('selected',false);
        }
        else if(prev.not('.only-me') && current.hasClass('only-me')){
            opts.attr('selected',false);
        }
        prev = $(this).find('option:selected');
        $(".chosen-select").trigger('chosen:updated');
    });
});
```